# Selection in TableView with merged columns

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In the simplified code below I have hard coded the first row to span all three columns of a TableView.

It seems to work well apart from selection. If I have the first row selected and press right, the selection goes to the cell with a width of zero and so seems to disappear. Likewise, if the middle cell of the second row is selected and up is pressed, the selection goes to the same hidden cell.

Is there anyway of telling the selection model that certain cells should be ignored? Or is it more likely I have to write a selection model from scratch?

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableSkinTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("This should span columns because it is long", "", ""),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "079155882"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "079155883"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "079155884"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "079155885")
        );

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<Person>() {
            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new TableRowSkin<TableSkinTest.Person>(this) {
                    @Override
                    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
                        checkState();
                        if (cellsMap.isEmpty()) return;
                        ObservableList<? extends TableColumnBase> visibleLeafColumns = getVisibleLeafColumns();
                        if (visibleLeafColumns.isEmpty()) {
                            super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);
                            return;
                        }
                        TableRow<TableSkinTest.Person> control = getSkinnable();
                        // layout the individual column cells
                        double width;
                        double height;

                        final double verticalPadding = snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset();
                        final double horizontalPadding = snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset();
                        final double controlHeight = control.getHeight();

                        int index = control.getIndex();

                        for (int column = 0, max = cells.size(); column < max; column++) {
                            TableCell<TableSkinTest.Person, ?> tableCell = cells.get(column);
                            width = snapSize(tableCell.prefWidth(-1)) - snapSize(horizontalPadding);
                            height = Math.max(controlHeight, tableCell.prefHeight(-1));
                            height = snapSize(height) - snapSize(verticalPadding);
                            if (index == 0 && column > 0) {
                                width = 0; // Hard code for simplification
                            } else if (index == 0) {
                                double width1 = snapSize(cells.get(1).getTableColumn().getWidth());
                                double width2 = snapSize(cells.get(2).getTableColumn().getWidth());
                                width += width1;
                                width += width2;
                            }
                            tableCell.resize(width, height);
                            tableCell.relocate(x, snappedTopInset());
                            x += width;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        TableColumn<Person,String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        TableColumn<Person,String> numberCol = new TableColumn<>("Number");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        numberCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("number"));

        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, numberCol);
        table.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setPrefWidth(100));

        table.setItems(data);

        pane.setCenter(table);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty number;
        private Person(String fName, String lName, String nNumber) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.number = new SimpleStringProperty(nNumber);
        }
        public String getFirstName() {return firstName.get();}
        public void setFirstName(String fName) {firstName.set(fName);}
        public String getLastName() {return lastName.get();}
        public void setLastName(String fName) {lastName.set(fName);}
        public String getNumber() {return number.get();}
        public void setNumber(String number) {this.number.set(number);}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting :-) My bet is that a custom selection model will not help much (not without letting it go very, very dirty): a clean implementation would override its navigation methods to cope with merged cells - unfortunately, behaviour doesn't use them (can't in all cases, as the api is incomplete, missing methods like clearAndSelectNext). So you would have to override the base select(..) to adjust which would severely violate its contract. No half-way clean way out, IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway of telling the selection model that certain cells should be ignored?

No, selectionModels have no notion of un/selectable.

> Or is it more likely I have to write a selection model from scratch?

Strictly speaking, a custom TableViewSelectionModel can't be implemented from scratch - it extends MultipleSelectionModelBase which is package private (as is TableViewArrayListSelectionModel, a static class inside TableView). The nearest to "scratch" would be to basically c&p TableViewArrayListSelectionModel and implement ignoring cells as needed. Would require dirty, reflective access to hidden super methods/fields ...

IMO, there is no nice solution to your requirement (short of writing a TableView from scratch). A possible dirty (at a similar level as your skin laying out over-spanned cells with width 0) might be to keep the spanning cell selected if any of the spanned cells is selected. Still has a slight useability glitch in that there is no perceptible change on left/right - but at least the selection doesn't disappear.

A crude version (PlainTableCell is c&p default in TableColumn):

```
public static class SpanTableCell<S, T> extends PlainTableCell<S, T> {

    private ListChangeListener<TablePosition> selectedListener = c -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded() || c.wasRemoved()) {
                updateSelection();
            }
        }
    };

    private WeakListChangeListener weakSelectedListener 
            = new WeakListChangeListener<>(selectedListener);

    private ChangeListener<TableView> tableViewListener = (t, old, value) -> {
        if (old != null && old.getSelectionModel() != null) {
            old.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().removeListener(weakSelectedListener);
        }
        if (value != null && value.getSelectionModel() != null) {
            value.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener(weakSelectedListener);
        }
        updateSelection();
    };

    private WeakChangeListener weakTableViewListener = new WeakChangeListener(tableViewListener);

    public SpanTableCell() {
        tableViewProperty().addListener(weakTableViewListener);
    }

    private void updateSelection() {
        // super will handle (hard-coded not span condition for simplicity)
        if (!isInCellSelectionMode() || getIndex() != 0) return;
        // TableViewSelectionModel doesn't support row selection in
        // cellSelectionMode
        TableViewSelectionModel<S> selectionModel = getTableView()
                .getSelectionModel();
        boolean rowSelected = false; 
        ObservableList<TableColumn<S, ?>> columns = getTableView()
                .getVisibleLeafColumns();
        for (TableColumn<S, ?> tableColumn : columns) {
            rowSelected = rowSelected
                    || selectionModel.isSelected(getIndex(), tableColumn);
        }
        boolean finalSelected = rowSelected;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // need to defer, super gets into the way
            updateSelected(finalSelected);
        });
    }

    private boolean isInCellSelectionMode() {
        TableView<S> tableView = getTableView();
        if (tableView == null) return false;
        TableSelectionModel<S> sm = tableView.getSelectionModel();
        return sm != null && sm.isCellSelectionEnabled();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra. I was hoping that JavaFX wouldn't require horrible hacks like I'm used to with Swing. Shame. Quick question, I can't find TableViewBitSelectionModel anywhere (in 8 update 20). Did you mistype or am I blind?

Comment: @Boomah my error - the name is TableViewArrayListSelectionModel (darn, all those inconsistencies, similar in ListView is called ListViewBitSelectionModel ;)

Comment: one more question - why PlainTableCell rather than TableCell?

Comment: @Boomah just an example :-) TableCell isn't useful as is, needs to override updateItem(...) to show anything, and that's what plain (aka: default from TableColumn) does.

Comment: I can't come up with a better hack than yours at the moment so I have marked it as correct. I will probably have to add hacks on top of it to get the left/right keys working as expected. Overall very messy but thanks so much for the help.